# How do I create a pdf with pdfLatex

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I have just installed TeXLive on Windows 8.1.

I have a source file I can access with the TeXworks editor(pdfLaTeX type).

How do I create a pdf from it?

Comment: Is there a green button (triangle) at upper left of the TeXworks window? Click it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Thank you RobtAll. A pdf has been created on "TexLiveDocs".